# How to integrate Banshee into the system tray for gnome

Tags: gnome, banshee

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and I recently installed Gnome 3. I miss the Banshee unity plugin for the system tray I was wondering how to incorporate that into the system tray for Gnome.

That is probably the only thing that I miss from Unity. I would hate to go back to it just for that unity plug-in. Or if there was a way to pick and choose what I liked about unity while still using Gnome that would be good too.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add integration for Gnome Shell?  Unity is run on Gnome 3 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! Here is a "how to" on how you install the extension:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/gnome-shell-mediaplayer-extension.html

As it says at the bottom of the post you also need to install gnome-tweak-tool to be able to activate it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to install a third party plugin to control the player from the top-bar sound menu

First of all make sure to have GNOME Tweak Tool (`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`), then install the plugin itself:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer
```

Relog and activate the plugin through GNOME Tweak Tool (aka: Advanced Settings) -> Shell Extensions